# If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm getting this error and it's still not clear for me why is this happening, for me is because the dataset I'm currently using have some blank spaces because this error repeats a couple times once the code is compiled

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
10 fits failed out of a total of 10.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 680, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py", line 1508, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 581, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 964, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 746, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'delivered'
```

I'm currently working in Collab so I'll attach the code here if you guys could explain me how to solve it'll be a huge help!

next part of the error, looks like is because the models check

```
  warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)
LR: nan (nan)
LDA
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
10 fits failed out of a total of 10.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.
```

Code I'm using is this one:

```
url = "train_set.csv"
names = ['ID', 'order_status', 'order_products_value', 'order_freight_value', 'order_items_qty', 'order_sellers_qty', 'order_purchase_timestamp', 'order_aproved_at', 'order_estimated_delivery_date', 'order_delivered_customer_date', 'customer_city', 'customer_state', 'customer_zip_code_prefix', 'product_category_name_english', 'product_name_lenght', 'product_description_lenght', 'product_photos_qty', 'target']
dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)

print(dataset.shape)

print(dataset.head(100))

print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")

print(dataset.describe())

dataset.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, layout=[12,2], sharex=False, sharey=False)
pyplot.show()

array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:17]
y = array[:,17]
print(y)
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))


# Here is where the errors are shown


results = []
names = []
print("---- X - Train ---------")
print(X_train)
print(Y_train)

for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    print(name)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold.get_n_splits(X_train, Y_train), scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm guessing your 'order status' column is made up of strings. How would you like the model to fit a column of strings?

Comment: Yeh I was thinking in removing that column but It's needed, because it has 3 statuses, like Delivered, Shipped, and cancelled, so the idea is to show all of them and drop the null ones as na, there are some blank spaces which means it doesn't have any status

Comment: You'll need to convert any string columns to numeric ones. Try dummying them out.

Comment: Yeh looks like it'll be the easier and faster way,  thanks a bunch!